# recommendation movie machine learning X_train

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Hi for my recommendation movie I use TF-IDF, but I have a shape error.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 2), min_df=0, stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train.summary)
tfidf_matrix.shape
```

OutPut :

```
 (3933, 56162)
```

then :

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel

# Compute the cosine similarity matrix
cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)

def get_recommendations(title):
    # Get the index of the movie that matches the title
    idx = indices[title.lower()]
    summary = data.summary[idx]
    tfidf_vect = tfidf.transform([summary])
    cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_vect)
    dis = cosine_sim - (np.abs(data.release_date - 
    data.release_date[idx]/56000)).to_numpy().reshape((-1,1)) 
    movie_indices = dis.argsort(axis=0)[-5:][::-1].reshape((-1))
    return pd.DataFrame(data[['title','release_date']].iloc[movie_indices])
```

Output Error :

```
 ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3933,1) (4917,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use python broadcasting for any shape . Two dimensions are compatible when

- they are equal, or
- one of them is 1

If these conditions are not met, a ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together exception is thrown, indicating that the arrays have incompatible shapes. The size of the resulting array is the maximum size along each dimension of the input arrays.

Please check the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for details if you are not familiar with python broadcasting.

Comment: I use this :

data.release_date[idx]/56000)).to_numpy().reshape((-1)); and it's not working